# How can i calculate in python the alignement for determinating if a figure is a cross or not and in a "middle case" give a probability?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have these kind of images, a trident:

[image: trident]

and the cross figure:

[image]

I implement this code for determinating the differences between a cross and a trident.
I calculated the extreme point' position and the junction point of the figure.
After that, i calculate if the opposite extreme points are at the same line with the junction point. If yes, i have a cross if not, it is a trident.
I use an approximation flag for determinating tha alignation.

I tested the code with many images but i'm not satisfied of the results.

Below i wrote coordinates of tridents that are not identifyied like a trident:

first trident:

```
#junction point
[(86, 112)]
#extreme points
[(39, 125), (48, 159), (49, 159), (133, 118)]
```

second trident:

```
#junction point
[(74, 58)]
#extreme points
[(67, 61), (75, 51), (81, 56), (81, 63)]
```

third trident:

```
#junction point
[(128, 448)]
#extreme points
[(93, 538), (115, 358), (217, 358), (218, 494)]
```

forth trident:

```
#junction point
[(62, 100)]
#extreme points
[(59, 97), (59, 98), (62, 103), (65, 98)]
```

image of the fourth trident:
[image: fourthtrident]

Clearly is a trident, but for my code: is a "doubt" case.
What can i do for improving the code?
I do not think it is a matter of changing the "doubt range".

with app = 1.0 and appmax = 1.2 i get similar result.

My code:

```
#app is the mininum approximation flag. < 2 is a aligned
app =2
def is_aligned (p1,p2,p3, approx = app):
    appmax = 3 #appmax is the maximum approximation flag. >3 is not aligned 
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    x3, y3 = p3

    #print("abs dist")
    #print(abs(((y3-y1) / (y2-y1)) - ((x3-x1) / (x2-x1))))
    dist = abs(((y3-y1) / (y2-y1)) - ((x3-x1) / (x2-x1)))

    if  dist <= approx:
        percentdist = 100
        return  dist <= approx, percentdist
    else:
        propor1 = appmax-approx #proxMax-proxMin
        propor2 =  dist - approx #approxmin
        percentdist = 100*propor2/propor1
        return dist<=appmax, percentdist
listalign = list()
listalign2= list()
def is_crux(v1, v2, v3, v4, o, approx=app):
    others = [v2, v3, v4]
    percentage = 200

    for v in others:
        print("iscrux1")
        align, percentage = is_aligned(v1, v, o, approx)        
        if align:
            listalign.append(percentage)
            #print("percentage")
            #print(percentage)            
            others.remove(v)
            align2, percentage2 = is_aligned(others[0], others[1], o, approx)
            if align2:                  
                percentage = percentage + percentage2
                listalign2.append(percentage2)
                return True, percentage
            break
    return False, percentage
listapercent =  list()
def angles(bpoints, epoints):
    bcoord = bpoints
    ecoord = epoints
    angvero = 2

    if (len(bpoints) == 1 and len(epoints) == 4):
        angvero, percentage = is_crux(ecoord[0], ecoord[1], ecoord[2], ecoord[3], bcoord[0])
        #print("percentage")
        #print(percentage)
        listapercent.append(percentage)
        # 3 cases: 1 if true (100-100) 1 if false (100-100 preso da is crux) and 1 if  doubt (100 e 40  o 30 e 70)
        if(angvero == True and percentage == 200):
            angvero = 1
            return angvero
        elif(angvero == False and percentage == 200):
            angvero = 0
            return angvero
        else:
            #calculating second %%%

            somma = percentage
            prob1 = 100 * 100 / somma
            #print("prob1")
            #print(prob1)            
            # obtaining percentage
            prob2 = 100 * (percentage/2) / somma
            #print("prob2")
            #print(prob2)

            angvero = "doubt"
        #print(angvero)
         #angvero = angles(erows,ecols, brows, bcols)
    elif(len(bpoints) == 1 and len(epoints) == 3):
        angvero = 0
        return angvero
    elif(len(bpoints) == 0 and len(epoints) == 3):
        angvero = 0
        return angvero
    #print(angvero)
    return angvero
```